# To async or not to async ajax request? When is it acceptable to use async=false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I understanding form reading many posts were async=false on the ajax request is not really the method for which to ajax requests. However is there a way for me to know the difference decide which one to use or always use async?

I'm currently faced with with a challenge in understanding ajax and ajax with callbacks and when to use callbacks. I have here a button where I click on so that I can have grialicious `http://suprb.com/apps/gridalicious/` append the items I need to #my-grid div container. However the ajax request will always run after it returns my items. So the only method for me right now to make this work is to do `request.async=false` to make it work synchronously. But is this approach the correct way? Or is there a better way to refactor my code?

```
$('#loadMoreButton').click(function(){
  var $grid = $('#my-grid').gridalicious('append',loadMoreUserFeed());
})


function loadMoreUserFeed(){

  var loadMoreButton = $('#loadMoreButton')
  var items = new Array;

  var request = {

    success: function(response){
      $.each(response.results.items,function(){

        myitem = document.createElement('div');
        myitem.className = 'my-item';

        items.push(myitem)

      }
    },
    error: function(response){
      debugger;
    }
  }

  request.dataType= 'json';
  request.contentType = 'application/json';
  request.data = $(this).serialize();
  request.scriptCharset = "utf-8";
  request.url = '/my_url';
  request.type = "GET";
  request.async = true;

  $.ajax(request);

  return items;

}
```

I'm getting the following message when I use `request.async=false`. But when I do `request.async=true` an empty array will get returned to gridalicious prior to my items list prior to my request finishing.

`Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.`

To async or not to async ajax request? When is it acceptable to use async=false? If to chose to stay with async. How should I structure my execution of ajax?

**EDIT**

The following is a proposed change I've come up with to enable async=true to work:

```
$('#loadMoreButton').click(function(){

  loadMoreUserFeed()

})


function loadMoreUserFeed(){

  var loadMoreButton = $('#loadMoreButton')
  var items = new Array;

  var request = {

    success: function(response){
      $.each(response.results.items,function(){

        myitem = document.createElement('div');
        myitem.className = 'my-item';

        items.push(myitem)

      }
      $('#my-grid').gridalicious('append',items);
    },
    error: function(response){
      debugger;
    }
  }

  request.dataType= 'json';
  request.contentType = 'application/json';
  request.data = $(this).serialize();
  request.scriptCharset = "utf-8";
  request.url = '/my_url';
  request.type = "GET";
  request.async = true;

  $.ajax(request);

}
```

But I do not know if this would be the best approach.

**EDIT 2**

```
$('#loadMoreButton').click(function(){

  loadMoreUserFeed(makeDivItems)

})


function loadMoreUserFeed(callback){

  var request = {

    success: function(response){
      callback()
    },
    error: function(response){
      debugger;
    }
  }

  request.dataType= 'json';
  request.contentType = 'application/json';
  request.data = $(this).serialize();
  request.scriptCharset = "utf-8";
  request.url = '/my_url';
  request.type = "GET";
  request.async = true;

  $.ajax(request);

}


function makeDivItems(){

  var items = new Array;

  $.each(response.results.items,function(){

    myitem = document.createElement('div');
    myitem.className = 'my-item';

    items.push(myitem)

  }
  $('#my-grid').gridalicious('append',items);
}
```

Comment: _"When is it acceptable to use async=false"_ As per the warning - it's best avoided.  [The spec says](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#sync-warning) that browsers may _already_ experiment with throwing an error instead of displaying a warning, so it could (at least in theory) stop working at any time.  If you then stick with an async request, your question is then a dupe of this one: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I can only think of a good way to use sync when the page will unload and the request won't complete. James threw up a good link there.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I added a proposed fix. But I'm not sure if this is best approach. Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: @user805981 While your fix may work, I'd go with the callback approach as documented in the other question.  Right now your `loadMoreUserFeed` function is doing too much - it shouldn't need to know about `'#my-grid'` for instance, rather pass back the results through a callback to a function that does know about it.

Comment: Wherever an async model won't work, which may be when using some legacy stuff or certain browser features. For example, I had a project where users locked resourced when viewing a page and unlocked it when they navigated away or closed the, and we ended up having to synchronizing the unlock request to make it work within `onbeforeunload`. Ultimately, we'll have to redesign that whole feature to avoid this, but we're stuck with it for now.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I'm not sure what you mean by it shouldn't need to know about `#my-grid` could you please be more specific? is it possible that you show me a snippet or a gist? Thanks!

Comment: @JamesThorpe is edit 3 closer to that of what the callback you are saying?